# How to interpret coefficients from logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression

I ran a logistic regression (statsmodel) on my data with 60 features using the below code

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(y_train,X_train_std)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

I was able to see that few variables had `negative coefficient` and few had `positive coefficients`.

Am I right to understand that irrespective of sign of coefficients, all the below variables are significant predictors that influence the outcome?

Or does negative coefficient mean they don't have any influence on the model outcome? But `p-value` is significant. Am a bit confused. Can you help in simple terms please

The below output shows the records whose `p-values` were less than 0.05

[image]

Comment: the coefficient magnitude is what's relevant, the sign is just telling you whether the predicted probability grows when the feature grows (positive coefficient) or decreases when the feature grows (negative coefficient).

Comment: So, since I am predcting a binary outcome (disease occur or not), we need to have both positive and negative coefficient variables (with signifncant p-values). Am I right?

Comment: not necessarily, it's perfectly normal to have all positive, all negative, or both positive and negative coefficients.

Comment: Yeah, so positive coefficients indicate majorly influencing one class while negative coefficients indicate majorly influencing the other class. Right?

Comment: influencing is an awkward word choice but yes.

Comment: May I know what is the right word to use in this case? I can learn

Comment: This very closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20996/how-to-interpret-coefficients-from-a-logistic-regression

Comment: Many similar questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interpret%20%5blogistic-regression%5d

Comment: Hope you used regularization

Comment: I mean in `statsmodel`, I couldn't find an option to use regularization but in `scikit-learn` i used `regularization`

Comment: @The Great p-values were less than 0.05. p-values have nothing to do with significant or insignificant effect of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They are all significant but for certain thing.**

What do I mean? You are predicting evidence, i.e. first column of the following picture:

[image]

In other words you have "linear regression part"+ instead of y you have evidence. So changing values of independnet variable X (positive or negative) will influence different binary class (0 or 1), hence different values are significant for different thing. (they add some info)

Comment: So usually positive coefficients influence label 1 and negative coefficients influence Lable 0. My label 0 indicates - No disease and Label 1 indicates - Disease present

Comment: Or the other way around, it depends how you defined it. But you can check it easily: Take some columns of X that you can reason about (i.e. somehing known) and look if these values are positive and log probability is xyz than you can deduce what influences what. ALTERNATIVE. Use feature importance and see exactly what influences what class

Comment: By defining what do you mean? I have defined people who have disease as `1` and don't have disease as `0`

Comment: I mean if rows of X map to labels 1 or 0. If you switch the rows that point to label 1 now to point (be instances ) of label 0 you will get opposite interpretation.

Comment: Sure. dont forget to accept if you are satisfied.